# Pure Jump-Type Continuous Time Markov Processes with Unbounded Rates

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, operator-theory, markov-process, semigroup-of-operators

We know that the infinitesimal generator $G$ of any pure jump-type continuous time Markov process (on an lcscH state space, say $X$) with bounded jump rates is given by:
\begin{equation}
Gf(x)=q(x)\int\big(f(y)-f(x)\big)\rho(x,dy),
\end{equation}
for every bounded measurable $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$, where $q(\cdot)$ is the *jump rate function* (we have, for a fixed $c>0$, $|q(x)|<c$ for every $x\in X$)  and $\rho(x,\cdot)$ is the *jump distribution kernel*. We know that, since the jump rate function is uniformly bounded by $c$, the domain of $G$ is the set of all bounded measurable real-valued functions on $X$. Further, the boundedness of jump rates implies that the corresponding transition semigroup $(P_t)_{t\geq0}$ can be written as
\begin{equation}
P_t=e^{tG}\;\;\;\forall t\geq0.
\end{equation}
This characterization of the semigroup in terms of the generator can't be so easily done in case the jump rate function is unbounded. Even figuring out the domain of $G$ is not an easy task in that case. Can anyone cite any article / book where one can read further about how to find the domain of $G$ in case of unbounded jump rates? Help will be appreciated.